# Formatting multiple columns with lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, formatting

good morning,
I'd like to format different columns in one single command line. I started with this

```
df['col1']= df['col1'].map(lambda x: '%.0f' % x)
```

and it works great.
now I'm trying to extend the formatting process to multiple columns. I tried this:

```
df['col1', 'col2'] = df['col1', 'col2'].map(lambda x,y :'%.0f' % x, '%.3f' % y)
```

but with no success..
thanks to all

Comment: here the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)-

```
df[['Col1', 'Col2']].applymap(lambda x: '%.0f' % x)
```

**Output**

```
  Col1 Col2
0    1    1
1   32    3
2    4    4
3    5    6
4    4    3
5    6    2
```

Comment: The solution works great when the format is the same, but my problem is applying different format styles to different columns :)